# Coldfusion multiserver instance hangs

Tags: java, coldfusion

I have a coldfusion 8 multiserver setup with IIS in Windows 2008 Standard SP2 and when one instance "hangs" (I can't connect to the instance from fusion reactor) the web server throws a "503 service unavailable". The remains instance seems to works ok in fusion reactor but the website have only the 503. I have to restart jvm processes and IIS to get the website work again.

The jvm processes have the option -Xmx2048m and the instanaces have 2.5Gb allocated. Maybe the jvm process reach the 2Gb limit and stop working? Can be a problem between IIS and CF instances?

I'm new to CF debugging process, how can I find why the instance hangs?

Thanks

---

@Mr Nil: The server is 64bit. I'm googling for the posts of Mike Brunt. Thanks for pointing out.

@jfrobishow: Yes, it's reach the 2Gb. The other jvm settings:

```
java.args=-server -Xmx2548m -Xms768m -Dsun.io.useCanonCaches=false -XX:MaxPermSize=256m -XX:+UseParallelGC -Xbatch -Dcoldfusion.rootDir={application.home}/ -Djava.security.policy={application.home}/servers/cfusion/cfusion-ear/cfusion-war/WEB-INF/cfusion/lib/coldfusion.policy -Djava.security.auth.policy={application.home}/servers/cfusion/cfusion-ear/cfusion -war/WEB-INF/cfusion/lib/neo_jaas.policy
```

Comment: @Mr Nil: The server is 64bit. I'm googling for the posts of Mike Brunt. Thanks for pointing out.

@jfrobishow: Yes, it's reach the 2Gb. The other jvm settings:

    java.args=-server -Xmx2548m -Xms768m -Dsun.io.useCanonCaches=false -XX:MaxPermSize=256m -XX:+UseParallelGC -Xbatch -Dcoldfusion.rootDir={application.home}/ -Djava.security.policy={application.home}/servers/cfusion/cfusion-ear/cfusion-war/WEB-INF/cfusion/lib/coldfusion.policy -Djava.security.auth.policy={application.home}/servers/cfusion/cfusion-ear/cfusion -war/WEB-INF/cfusion/lib/neo_jaas.policy

Answer (score 1):

If you're running a 32bit version of JRun you can't assign more than 1Gb of RAM. You can only assign that amount of RAM with the 64bit version of JRun.

This is an issue with the 32bit version of the JVM not with ColdFusion or JRun. The maximum you can use with the 32bit JVM in 1.4GB, but by the time you've assigned PermGen space there's only 1/1.2GB left available.

I'm no expert on this, but I know a man who is.  Do a google search for ColdFusion JVM Tuning and Mike Brunt.  You will find a wealth of information on this topic.

Answer (score 0):

Do you really need that much RAM assigned to the heap? Do you see the usage creeping up to 2GB in FusionReactor before it crashes?

What are the other JVM settings?